# How can you layout a JavaFX Node that is padded with a proportion of the available space?

Tags: javafx, layout

It is fairly easy to use the standard layout Panes in JavaFX to get fixed padding around a content node.

However are there settings for any of the standard layout Panes that would put the content in the middle ¾ of the pane's width with padding of 1/8 of the width on each side?

Comment: not that I'm aware of .. write your own (though it might be non trivial)

Comment: Wrap it in a one-row grid pane and set percentage widths on the three columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, as [suggested by James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60822915/how-can-you-layout-a-javafx-node-that-is-padded-with-a-proportion-of-the-availab#comment107612762_60822915), use a `GridPane` with the appropriate constraints to accomplish this. Here's an example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Region region = new Region();
    region.setStyle("-fx-background-color: firebrick;");

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.add(region, 0, 0);

    ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints(0, Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    cc.setPercentWidth(75);
    cc.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    cc.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
    grid.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);

    RowConstraints rr = new RowConstraints(0, Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    rr.setPercentHeight(100);
    rr.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    rr.setValignment(VPos.CENTER);
    grid.getRowConstraints().add(rr);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(grid, 500, 300));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Another option is to create your own layout which, assuming I didn't make a mistake, is not too difficult:

```java
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class CustomPane extends Pane {

  // value should be between 0.0 (0%) and 1.0 (100%)
  private final DoubleProperty widthRatio =
      new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "widthRatio", 0.75) {

        @Override
        protected void invalidated() {
          requestLayout();
        }
      };
  public final void setWidthRatio(double widthRatio) { this.widthRatio.set(widthRatio); }
  public final double getWidthRatio() { return widthRatio.get(); }
  public final DoubleProperty widthRatioProperty() { return widthRatio; }

  public CustomPane() {}

  public CustomPane(double widthRatio) {
    setWidthRatio(widthRatio);
  }

  @Override
  protected void layoutChildren() {
    double ratio = getWidthRatioClamped();
    double x = snappedLeftInset();
    double y = snappedTopInset();
    double w = getWidth() - snappedRightInset() - x;
    double h = getHeight() - snappedBottomInset() - y;

    // could do the same thing with the height if you want
    x = snapPositionX(x + ((w - w * ratio) / 2.0));
    w = snapSizeX(w * ratio);

    for (Node child : getManagedChildren()) {
      layoutInArea(child, x, y, w, h, -1.0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }
  }

  private double getWidthRatioClamped() {
    return Math.max(0.0, Math.min(1.0, getWidthRatio()));
  }
}
```

Note that both solutions will take the child nodes' min/pref/max widths and heights into account. If the child node is not resizable (e.g. `ImageView`, `MediaView`, etc.) then it won't work as expected. Though you can of course create workarounds for non-resizable nodes. For instance, [here's another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58516268/6395627) which creates a "resizable `ImageView`".

Also, note that both solutions layout the children in the area available *after* the space taken up from any padding and borders is subtracted.

Comment: Another way to create a custom layout would be to subclass GridPane with initialisation code that sets the row and column constraints that you suggested. (Thanks for the suggestions.)

Comment: That definitely works, though I hesitate to subclass solely to simplify configuration. I would be more likely to create some utility method if using the `GridPane` approach.